# Storing and reading objects in to objects or array

Tags: arrays, powershell, object

I need to create VEEAM Replication jobs. When creating the job I need to provide a list of SourceNetworks and matching TargetNetworks. I have a CSV file that has the matching list in text and then I run a cmdlet to retrieve the matching network object.

CSV:

```
SourcePortGroup, TargetPortGroup
VLAN 103,LAN0_DMZ
VLAN 120,LAN0_JDE
VLAN 121,LAN0_IT-BDC
```

I wrote a foreach in which I retrieve the network object using:

```
foreach ($item in $csvlist) {
  Get-VBRServer -Name $SourceESXi | Get-VBRViServerNetworkInfo | Where-Object {
    $_.NetworkName -eq $Mapping.SourcePortGroup
  }
  Get-VBRServer -Name $TargetESXi | Get-VBRViServerNetworkInfo | Where-Object {
    $_.NetworkName -eq $Mapping.TargetPortGroup
  }
}
```

This works when debugging, I get the correct result, which is an object. But now I need to store each of them in a new object or in an array, so that later on when creating the job I can easily use the source and target mapping.

I have no clue on what the best way is to store the results and then call them when needed.

Comment: `$var = Get-VBRServer ...`

Comment: Ok, but this is a loop. So I will be calling the get-vbrserver 100 times. And I need to store those results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that each `Get-VBRServer` statement produces only a single item per iteration you could for example use a hashtable for mapping source to target networks:

```
$networks = @{}
foreach ($item in $csvlist) {
  $key = '{0}/{1}' -f 
  $networks[$key] = @{
    'Source' = Get-VBRServer -Name $SourceESXi |
               Get-VBRViServerNetworkInfo |
               Where-Object { $_.NetworkName -eq $Mapping.SourcePortGroup }
    'Target' = Get-VBRServer -Name $TargetESXi |
               Get-VBRViServerNetworkInfo |
               Where-Object { $_.NetworkName -eq $Mapping.TargetPortGroup }
  }
}
```